# Icon is not displaying in react-navigation-header-buttons (React Native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-button

I am trying to add an icon to the headerRight using react-navigation-header-buttons library. But the title of the icon is displaying instead of the icon.

This is the code where icon should display.

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

import { MEALS } from '../data/DummyData';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import { HeaderButton } from '../components/CustomHeaderButton';

const MealDetailScreen = props => {
    const mealId = props.route.params.mealId;
    const selectedMeal = MEALS.find(meal => meal.id == mealId);
    const [headerTitle, setHeaderTitle] = useState();

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setHeaderTitle(() => selectedMeal === undefined ? props.route.params.title : selectedMeal.title)
        props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitle: headerTitle,
            headerRight: () => (
                <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                    <Item
                        title="Favourite"
                        iconName="ios-star"
                        onPress={() => {
                            console.log('Mark as favorite!');
                        }}
                    />
                </HeaderButtons>
            )
        });
    }, [props.navigation, headerTitle]);


    return (
        <View>
            <Text>The Meal Detail Screen!</Text>
            <Text>{selectedMeal.title}</Text>
            <Button title="Go Back to Categories!" onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.popToTop();
            }} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

export default MealDetailScreen;
```

This is the custom component for the header button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderButton } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const CustomHeaderButton = props => {
    return (
        <HeaderButton
            {...props}
            IconComponent={Ionicons}
            iconSize={23}
            color={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor}
        />);
}

export default CustomHeaderButton;
```

Only the **title** in the  is displaying at the headerRight.

```
<Item
  title="Favourite"
  iconName="ios-star"
  onPress={() => {
  console.log('Mark as favorite!');
  }}
/>
```

React Native version: 5
react-navigation-header-buttons version: 3.0.5

Answer (score 7):

The problem lies in your component import statement.

Instead of

```
import { HeaderButton } from '../components/CustomHeaderButton';
```

Type

```
import HeaderButton from '../components/CustomHeaderButton';
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem with 2 changes:

1. Instead of :

```
import { HeaderButton } from '../components/CustomHeaderButton';
```

Typed :

```
import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
```

2. I returned < HeaderButton > with arrow function and set it in headerRight as a variable headerRightButton :

```
MealDetailScreen.navigationOptions = (navigationData) => {
    const mealId = navigationData.navigation.getParam('mealId');
    const selectedMeal = MEALS.find(meal => meal.id === mealId);
    const headerRightButton = () => {
        return (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item 
                                title= 'Favorite'
                                iconName="ios-star"
                                onPress= {() => {
                                    console.log('Added to favorites');
                                }}
                            />
                            <Item 
                                title= 'Favorite'
                                iconName= "ios-star-outline"
                                onPress= {() => {
                                    console.log('Added to favorites2');
                                }}
                            /> 
                      </HeaderButtons>
        );
    };
    return {
            headerTitle: selectedMeal.title,
            headerRight: (headerRightButton)
        };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I found in the example given, the `IconComponent` is (for whatever reason) not being passed down into `Item`. Since IconComponent is undefined, a Text component is used instead. That logic can be seen [here](https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-header-buttons/blob/da5b86cd77a0bbbd1d41c7480272828061e1f566/src/HeaderItems.js#L35).

The way I approached this is to create a custom component that would return the `HeaderButtons` instead of `HeaderButton`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Colors from '../constants/colors';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderButtons, HeaderButton } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

const CustomHeaderButton = (props) => (
  <HeaderButton
    IconComponent={Ionicons}
    iconSize={23}
    color={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor}
    {...props}
  />
);

export const CustomHeaderButtons = (props) => {
  return <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton} {...props} />;
};
export { Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
```

Now you can use it like this:

```js
import { CustomHeaderButtons, Item } from '../components/HeaderButton';
...
MealDetailScreen.navigationOptions = navigationData => {
  const mealId = navigationData.navigation.getParam('mealId');
  const selectedMeal = MEALS.find(meal => meal.id === mealId);
  return {
    headerTitle: selectedMeal.title,
    headerRight: () => (
      <CustomHeaderButtons>
        <Item
          title='Favorite'
          iconName='ios-star'
          onPress={() => { console.log('Marked as favorite!') }}
        />
      </CustomHeaderButtons>
    )
  };
};
```

Comment: IconComponent={Ionicons}  -> can i use multiple icon library inside IconComponent, so that i use different icon name from different library,  IconComponent={Ionicons | Fontawesome}   something like this

Answer (score 0):

This could be problem with background color of your header.

My Case: Header button appeared in Android but not in iOS(iPhone).

Resolution: Change below line to apply background independent of platform

From

```
color={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor}
```

to

```
color='white'
```